# Facebook Login on Both Web and Hybrid Mobile App

Tags: cordova, browser, ionic-framework, facebook-login

I'm using Ionic for hybrid mobile app dev on iOS and Android and also have a web application for use in desktop and mobile browsers.

The apps all have Facebook Login capability but I'm finding that the hybrid apps for iOS and Android need to use a different Facebook App ID because Facebook does not allow login to occur from different domains on the same app ID.

The browser-based (web) app runs on a normal domain while the Ionic apps run on localhost since they are served via cordova.

Is there any way for a web app to share a Facebook App ID with a hybrid mobile app?